# XCode-> Support Wirelessly Connected Devices [Opened]

Tags: xcode, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the Xcode 4.2 preference “Support Wirelessly Connected Devices” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266391/what-does-the-xcode-4-2-preference-support-wirelessly-connected-devices-do)

XCode4.2, Preferences->General,There is a choice, iOS Device Discovery--Support Wirelessly Connected Devices.

Any body know how to use it?

Thanks.