# Wireless Debugging in Xcode4.2

Tags: xcode, debugging, wireless

When I use wireless debugging in Xcod e4.2 it tells me:

> Don't know how to run. Try "help target".

Please see "[Wireless debugging in xcode](http://thomashajcak.com/2011/10/20/wireless-debugging-in-xcode/)" for more information.

Comment: 4.2 has wireless debug? really??  I thought it only has wireless sync.

Comment: yes, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769019/xcode-support-wirelessly-connected-devices-opened

Comment: same with me, as the other commenter noted it's really broken

Comment: I am facing same problem.Is it solved?

Comment: What about using superDB http://shopify.github.io/superdb/ ?

Answer (score 6):

Wireless debugging in Xcode 4.2 is still really unstable. I've only been able to get it up and running once or twice before needing to restart Xcode, disabling and reenabling wireless device support, restarting the device, and deleting the app from the device before trying it again (not necessarily in this order).

Hopefully they'll get it working better soon.

Comment: FYI, from Xcode engineering - "Xcode Wireless Debugging is removed from Xcode 4.3.1 (due to issues with the functionality). The intention is to add this functionality back in to Xcode 4.4 with Mountain Lion: if we are unable to, we'll be sure to get a release note filed."

Comment: I noticed this the other day. You'd think it wouldn't be available at all until it was functional.