# Develop iPad Wirelessly

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, osx-lion, xcode4.3

http://cl.ly/F0vv

As you can see, I don't see the 'Support Wirelessly Connected Devices' checkbox. Furthermore, before I updated to 4.3.1 (last week), I did see it - but it did not work.

Any ideas how to get it back and any tips on getting it to work? This is my work computer and my iPad is synced with a different computer, so I can't truly 'sync' it to this computer.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a comment to an answer for the question [Wireless Debugging in Xcode4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992491/wireless-debugging-in-xcode4-2/7996999#7996999)

> FYI, from Xcode engineering - "Xcode Wireless Debugging is removed from Xcode 4.3.1 (due to issues with the functionality). The intention is to add this functionality back in to Xcode 4.4 with Mountain Lion: if we are unable to, we'll be sure to get a release note filed."

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the correct answer. I would love an easy (reliable) way to develop on the iPad wirelessly!!