# XCode 4.3.3 - Lost "iOS Discovery Device" Option for Wifi testing

Tags: ios, xcode, wifi

I'm looking to test my app on iPad via WiFi, in internet I found a response but with my version of Xcode 4.3.3 the option **"iOS Discovery Device - Support Wirelessly Connected Devices"** doesn't exist.

Can anybody help me? Did Apple change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857052/1002727). Long story short (from that link):

> Edit: This feature is no longer available as of Xcode 4.3.1 It will
>   re-appear later when it has less issues (they are estimating in
>   version 4.4).

So I would suggest you check the developer preview of Xcode 4.5.

Comment: I have installed 4.5, but i don't know to start it again. The first time I installed has opened, but now opens 4.3.3 every time... thanks!

Comment: Xcode 4.6 doesn't support it either. 4.6 is the last version with GDB support, maybe with LLDB this feature will work properly and it will be reintroduced.