# Testing mobile via IP

Tags: android, iphone, testing

I have written some tests with Android test frame work for our android client and also some for iPhone with its framework.
I would like to run these tests on multiple devices and without USB connection...

Both iPhone's and Android's test frameworks requires that device will be connected to machine with the SDK with USB cable, right?

Is there a way to use instrumentation without the constraint of USB cable?
If there is such a way, can it be used on multiple device simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

For Android, nothing more simple, build the .apk. The, email it to the phones and install it ;-)

You just have to disable unknown sources (Settings > Applications > Unknown sources)

Comment: my problem is not distribution, but automation. how can I run automation on a remote device?

Comment: the question is can I run automation on device that is not connected via USB?

Comment: What do you say through "automation"

Comment: Tests. Unit tests and E2E tests.

Answer (score 0):

For the iOS part you could use an Ad Hoc Distribution Profile (you must have an Apple developer account to create it). You have to insert the UDID of each device before build the app.
Once the app archive is created you can use the iOS Beta Builder that allow you to put your app in your server so that the permitted device can download/install it directly.

[Introducing iOS Beta Builder](http://www.hanchorllc.com/2010/08/24/introducing-ios-beta-builder/)
[iOS Beta Builder GitHub page](https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder)
[iOS Beta Builder Mac AppStore](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ios%20beta%20builder%20app%20store&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGwQFjAI&url=https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/betabuilder-for-ios-apps/id415348946?mt=12&ei=rcWfUKGpMMSF4ATEuIGYDA&usg=AFQjCNEpd_M2akqJWTH2mEq55TNfDf9AlQ)

Comment: my problem is not distribution, but automation. how can I run automation on a remote device?

Comment: AFAIK now you can't. You were able to build your app through wi-fi but this option was removed from Xcode. Probably a new version will have this option again. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11094904/251513).