# Is it possible to send a developing App to my iPhone using wireless on Xcode5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I heard it is possible about Xcode4.3
But now I don't know...

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: This feature was not available after 4.2. Neither 4.3.1 nor 4.5 or 4.6 had this feature. And up to now Xcode 5 does not seems to have this feature

Comment: It's not natively supported by Xcode after Xcode 4.2, but there are ways around it. Check out the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807979/xcode-4-5-wirelessly-build-app-on-my-device and that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could jailbreak your iphone and use ssh.