# Possible to install .ipa without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ipa, iphone-developer-program

Is it possible to install an ipa on an iPhone (given enterprise provisioning profile) without iTunes? We are distributing an app to a non-technical audience within our company and want to simplify things as much as possible.

In the ideal case, we'd like to host the ipa on a site, and have the users browse to the site from their iPhone and install directly. Is something like this possible?

Comment: you can also check this "Make your own app store” http://stackoverflow.com/a/12808205

Comment: also http://www.diawi.com/ or http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air

Answer (score 1):

You can use this service: www.testflightapp.com

It is free. You can send invitations/notifications to the desired users and a new version or update is uploaded. Also you can share a link to anyone you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distribute the ipa through your own domain and server you can use [HockeyKit](http://hockeykit.net/). It's the free and open source "little brother" of HockeyApp, a hosted service to distribute app betas.

Here is what you need to do:

- Integrate the HockeyKit SDK in your app
- Install the server component on your web server
- Add the devices you want to distribute to in your Apple developer account and generate an ad hoc distribution certificate with those devices
- Build and archive with the ad hoc profile
- Upload the ipa and the profile to your webserver