# Is it possible to wirelessly debug an iphone webapp?

Tags: ios, debugging

I currently have to have my iPhone physically connected by USB to run remote debugging in Safari. Is it possible to do it via bluetooth or some other wireless method?

Comment: Once upon a time, there was wireless debugging. As of today, it's gone. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266391/what-does-the-xcode-4-2-preference-support-wirelessly-connected-devices-do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to plug the phone to your computer, is not possible to do it remotely so far.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: What about now?

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to do [wireless remote debugging using "Safari Technology Preview"](https://silvantroxler.ch/2018/wireless-remote-debugging-with-safari-on-ios/):

> Remote debugging with mobile Safari also works without a cable connection to the desktop computer. But you have to install Safari Technology Preview on your Mac as the stable Safari version currently does not support wireless remote debugging. Just do the same setup as described above, but connect the cable and open Safari on your iOS device. In Safari Technology Preview, make sure you **enabled “Show Develop menu in menu bar” and enable Develop → "Your mobile Device Name" → Connect via Network in the menu**. Now you can unplug the cable and check whether Develop → "Your mobile Device Name" still shows up on the desktop Safari.

Comment: I used my iPad as Hotspot for the MacBook and iPhone, but whenever I unplug the iPhone, it disappears from the devices list. It works fine with the cable. I have no way to check on another network at the moment. Do you know if that option is supposed to work on Hotspot?

Comment: Please read my question again. I used iPad as a hotspot for iPhone and MacBook. So they were in the same network, I guess.

Comment: Not sure but I guess it should work, given the setup was done correctly.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. Would you be able to confirm using your devices?

Comment: I do not have an iOS device available.

Comment: Okay, I will find out on another network in a few days, I will let you know what I found.

Comment: I found my mobile router and checked. So, it does work :) It turns out that you can't do it via hotspot. Good stuff with that wireless debug, pretty cool when you click *Start element selection* and then you can tap an element on your iPhone. I love it!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible now - I put it here to tie the threads - see here

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/333876/100894

Answer (score -1):

Currently, it is not possible to debug directly on iPhone from a Mac wirelessly. You will need to connect the iPhone via USB cable to a mac and then use the Safari Preview Technology browser.