# Xcode 6.1 debug without USB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, lldb

I am testing an integration with some hardware that requires the iPad to be plugged in via the lighting adapter. The problem is I don't have the Xcode debugger or any feedback from the application, it's like drawing in the dark.

I know in previous versions of Xcode you could do Wifi based debugging, is this confirmed in Xcode 6.1+ or do I have any other options?

Answer (score 4):

WiFi debugging has never been supported in any public releases of Xcode yet.

- There are third party hacks that may or may not work: https://github.com/Shopify/superdb
- There also reports that this works with some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857052/361247

But officially, this isn't supported.

Comment: Not true. There was an option for that in Xcode 4. According to this reddit thread it works now http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/2krdzc/xcode_without_cable/