# How to enable an iOS device wireless profiling using instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, instruments, xcode-instruments

According to the development documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/WorkingwithTargets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH10-SW1), we could be profile an iOS device without USB cable. I've tried for some times but didn't succeed. I've read the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266391/what-does-the-xcode-4-2-preference-support-wirelessly-connected-devices-do/7857052#7857052). Doesn't Xcode6 or Xcode7-beta support it any more? If this feature doesn't exist, why there is still the introduction of wireless profiling feature in the documentation? If anybody knows how to enable the wireless profiling, please tell me, thanks!

Forgave me that my English is poor and hope I've described the question clearly.

Comment: How about this bit? "Bonjour and multicast must also be enabled on your wireless network access point."

Comment: @Droppy I've noticed that tip. But didn't understand much better about it. Do you know how to setup ?

Comment: Depends on your router doesn't it.

Comment: @Droppy Do I need to setup Bonjour Service?