# Support Wirelessly Connected Devices option

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to check the support wireless option from Xcode preferences as the pic in this link :

[How to install app on iPad/iPhone without using USB cable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034779/how-to-install-app-on-ipad-iphone-without-using-usb-cable)

but in my Xcode 6.3.3 I don't have this option.
Does it still in another place ?

Comment: Set up wirelessly sync with iTunes first.

see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7857052/5235106

Comment: I did that. but in step 5  : In XCode, XCode menu -> Preferences -> General check the "Support Wirelessly Connected Devices". I don't have this option in my Xcode.

Comment: Please go to the final part of the answer, which starts with '9/2014 - I have a report that wifi device capability...'